# How is memcpy.c supposed to react to memory overlap?

Tags: c, memory, overlap

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of `memcpy`. However when I try it with overlapping memory tests, instead of a trace trap I receive a different result. For example with the following `main` function, the result would be `OveOveOveOveO�`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char buffer[] = "Overlap Test";
    ft_memcpy(buffer + 3, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
    printf("%s\n", buffer + 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I did put the `restrict` keywords in the function declaration, and I don't understand why the compiler wouldn't put it as a trace trap in this case. Of course chatgpt is useless finding an explanation for this as well. Would such a result be expected in case of memory overlap?

```
void    *ft_memcpy(void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t n)
{
    char    *ptr;
    char    *d;
    char    *s;

    d = dst;
    s = (char *)src;
    ptr = dst;
    if (src == NULL || n == 0)
        return (NULL);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        *d = *s;
        d++;
        s++;
        n--;
    }
    return (ptr);
}
```

Comment: I believe the glibc sources are freely available. Why not take a look at how the maintainers of the GCC did it?

Comment: I did try to look at these, but I have a hard time understanding apple's one, and the more accessible one i found on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-memcpy/ doesn't seem to differ much from mine.

Comment: `memcpy()` is undefined for overlapping regions so that it can be optimised for the non-overlapping case. `memmove()` is required to handle overlapping regions.

Comment: @marinsucks because geeksforgeeks one is same naive as yours and it is there to illustrate the problem. The real ones are writen much more optimized way. example: : https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memcpy.c

Comment: @marinsucks, Aside, no reason for `cast`.  Use `const char *s = src;`.

Comment: Historical adventures: https://lwn.net/Articles/414467/ <- glibc changed memcpy to copy in the opposite direction, broke flashplayer (both memcpy behaviors are valid, flashplayer was wrong to rely on undefined behavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of memcpy.

**Bug: Wrong return value**

When `n == 0`, `memcpy()` returns `dest`.  OP's code should perform likewise.

```
// if (src == NULL || n == 0)
//        return (NULL);
if (src == NULL) // memcpy(..., NULL, ...) is not defined.  Do whatever you want.
  return NULL;  // or maybe `n = 0;`
if (n == 0) 
  return dest;
```

**Bug: Insufficient space**

With `char buffer[] = "Overlap Test";`, `ft_memcpy(buffer + 3, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);` is a problem as `buffer + 3` does not have enough room for `strlen(buffer) + 1` characters. [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324340/how-is-memcpy-c-supposed-to-react-to-memory-overlap/77324542?noredirect=1#comment136333278_77324542)

---

> How is memcpy.c supposed to react to memory overlap?
> Would such a result be expected in case of memory overlap?

Given the 2 `restrict` in the function signature, using overlapping buffers is *undefined behavior* (UB).  There are no expected results.

```
void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);
```

Even if OP's `ft_memcpy()` functioned just like OP's compiler's `memcpy()` today, it is not certain it will tomorrow or on some other machine.  It is UB.

I recommend to **not test** for equivalent functionality with overlapping buffers - since it is UB.
Notice, that focus on this issue missed proper behavior when `n == 0`.

---

Consider instead "How is <strike>memcpy.c</strike> `memmove()` supposed to react to memory overlap?"

That is trickier.

> Copying takes place **as if** the `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` are first copied into a temporary array of `n` characters that does not overlap the objects pointed to by `s1` and `s2`, and then the `n` characters from the temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by `s1`.
> C23dr § 7.26.2.3 2

OP's code needs changes to meet that.  To do well is a challenge as the *usual* approach is to compare addresses.  Depending on which is greater, copy from the beginning or end of the source buffer.  Yet for user code, there is no defined way to compare arbitrary addresses for order.  Various tricks abound that *usually* work.

The below does not have UB, yet may not compile nor function exactly like `memmove()` on all machines.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void *ft_memmove(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n) {
  // Not needed as passing `NULL` for either pointer parameter is UB in memmove().
  if (dst == NULL || src == NULL) {
    n = 0;
  }
  // Weakness: uintptr_t is an optional type.
  uintptr_t d = (uintptr_t) dst;
  uintptr_t s = (uintptr_t) src;
  // Weakness: `d < s` is not a defined order compare of the pointers.
  if (d < s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      ((char*)dst)[i] = ((const char*)src)[i];
    }
  } else {
    while (n > 0) {
      n--;
      ((char*)dst)[n] = ((const char*)src)[n];
    }
  }
  return dst;
}
```

Comment: would you consider `while (n --> 0)` ?

Comment: @chqrlie Ah yes, the arrow operator.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of memcpy. However when I try it
> with overlapping memory tests, instead of a trace trap I receive a
> different result.

In this case (by the C standard) the result of `memcpy` is undefined.

> Would such a result be expected in case of memory overlap?

No, as it is UNDEFINED and you should have not been expecting anything.

> I did put the restrict keywords in the function declaration, and I
> don't understand why the compiler wouldn't put it as a trace trap in
> this case.

Because `restrict` does not work this way. It does not add any checks. It is **your** promise that your function will behave a certain way, allowing compiler to do more aggressive optimizations.

---

Nonsense UB deliberations:

Also, many x86 glibc `memcpy` implementations do not use single-byte copy, so your (naive) function will not be able to reproduce their behaviour.

Comment: So you mean that I should implement an overlap check directly into the function ? or redo the function from the beginning in an other way ?

Comment: @marinsucks overlap checks are very dificult in C language. Basically you cant implement them efficiently portable way. See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946095/is-it-possible-in-c-not-invoking-ub-to-check-if-two-objects-overlap

Comment: Restrict restricts the caller, not the callee. That sentence is reversed.

Comment: @marinsucks why would you want to waste time for such checks in a function that is not defined to do it? That is what `memmov` is intented to be used for. If you want to implement that as well, you can add overlap check there but why pollute `memcpy` function with extra checks?

Comment: @Gerhardh overlap checks in portable code are very expensive

Comment: @0___________ one reason more to not pollute `memcpy` with it. As any caller that would rely on proper handling of overlapping areas is supposed to use `memmov` anyway.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm checking for these as I know the tests of my school are very rigorous, and it's also the occasion for me to wrap my head around general memory concepts, so I'm trying to make it work exactly like the og. But yeah, I might be wasting time on this though, I'll try a few things and come back when I'll be more comfortable with this then !

Comment: @marinsucks with "waste time" I don't mean you spending time to do it as an excercise. I mean adding extra code that is executed on each call of the function. If you are supposed to reimplement the behaviour of `memcpy` as defined in the standard, then any test using overlapping areas is an invalid test.