How to create a restrict pointer out of a non-restrict pointer
Here is a motivating example
void foo(int *A, int *B, int *N) {
  for (int k = 0; k < *N; k++)
    A[k] += B[k];
}

Compiler can't vectorize this loop because it assumes that A and N alias. Adding a restrict to N enables vectorization. e.g., https://godbolt.org/z/joMrhEM8K
void foo(int *A, int *B, int *__restrict N) {
    for (int k = 0; k < *N; k++)
        A[k] += B[k];
}

generates
.LBB0_9:
        ldp     q0, q3, [x11, #-16]
        subs    x12, x12, #8
        ldp     q1, q2, [x10, #-16]
        add     x10, x10, #32
        add     v0.4s, v0.4s, v1.4s
        add     v1.4s, v3.4s, v2.4s
        stp     q0, q1, [x11, #-16]
        add     x11, x11, #32
        b.ne    .LBB0_9

Which is good. But I want to create a restricted pointer out of N and not modify the function declaration. e.g., something like
void foo(int *A, int *B, int *N) {
    int *__restrict p = N;
    for (int k = 0; k < *p; k++)
        A[k] += B[k];
}

But this doesn't work. Any way to achieve this?
The reason I'd like to achieve this is because then I can 'version' the code without adding __restrict in the declaration. like:
// Returns true if X, Y don't alias.
bool no_alias(int* X, int *Y);

void foo(int *A, int *B, int *N) {
    if (no_alias(A,N)) { // assuming I have a way to figure out that A and N don't alias at runtime.
      int *__restrict p = N;
      for (int k = 0; k < *p; k++)
        A[k] += B[k];
    } else {
      for (int k = 0; k < *p; k++)
          A[k] += B[k];
    }
}


Why are you passing the length as a pointer in the first place?

Why do you use __restrict? Isn't this a standard qualifier?

You need to restrict something in function parameters anyway https://godbolt.org/z/v56KKq6r4

@NathanOliver that's a good point. I should just hoist it. Thanks! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

@0___________ no, I can't change the function specification. What happens when they do alias?

@A.K. have two versions. BTW how do you check if they alias? Most methods invoke UB and those which do not are very inefficient.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946095/is-it-possible-in-c-not-invoking-ub-to-check-if-two-objects-overlap

C or C++, you must make up your mind about that. You are compiling with a C++ compiler which will eventually come back and bite you if the intention is to write C.

@0___________ > BTW how do you check if they alias? This is a specific case where std::abs(std::distance(A, N)) < *N should suffice

@A.K.: std::distance(A, N) would be pedantically UB when no aliasing happens, but the check can be done without UB comparing A, N and A + *N with std::less

good point! thanks for correcting.

Another option is to just get rid of the possibility by assigning the value to an intermediary.
void foo(int *A, int *B, int *N) {
    if (no_alias(A, N)) {
        const int n = *N;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            A[k] += B[k];
    }
    else {
        for (int k = 0; k < *N; k++)
            A[k] += B[k];
    }
}


Does declaring n as const make a difference?

I would not expect making n as const to make a difference.

@ThomasMatthews I shouldn't.  the compiler can prove that it isn't modified but for good coding practice the const should be there

@ThomasMatthews Storing the value down in a temporary variable is the big difference.

Close enough, the correct solution is to use const int n = *N; conditionally when no_alias is true. please edit your answer.

@A.K. Is no_alias a standard function?  Also, why is it needed?  Even if it is an alias this approach breaks the aliasing since n will never change.

As this is a specific case bool no_alias(A, N) { return std::abs(std::distance(A, N)) < *N; } should work. However, when we hoist the *N outside of loop, it changes the semantics of the program when A and N do alias.

@A.K. Answer updated.  If you want to change something about it feel free to edit it.

Call a version of the function with the restrict qualifier.
void foo_restrict(int *A, int *B, int *restrict N) {
  for (int k = 0; k < *N; k++)
    A[k] += B[k];
}

void foo(int *A, int *B, int *N) {
    if (no_alias(A,N)) { // assuming I have a way to figure out that A and N don't alias at runtime.
      foo_restrict(A, B, N);
    } else {
      for (int k = 0; k < *N; k++)
          A[k] += B[k];
    }
}


I assume, where you have written *p that you intend *N.    Interesting assumption about being able to implement no_alias() - I suspect that implementing it will either rely on compiler-specific extensions, or on some form of undefined behaviour.

@Peter: With restriction from semantic of above function, boo no_alias(int* A, int* N) { return std::less{}(N, A) or std::less{}(A + *N, N); }

@Peter Yes, I was copy/pasting from the OP's version that used p (even in the else block that didn't declare it).

@Jarod42 That works in C++, there's nothing analogous in C.

You must use the builtins __builtin_assume
#include <cassert>

bool no_alias(int* X, int* Y);

void foo(int *A, int *B, int *N) {
    int* p = N;
    if (no_alias(A, N)) {
        __builtin_assume(p != A);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < *p; k++) {
        A[k] += B[k];
    }
}

And maybe add the compilation option -fstrict-aliasing (gcc, strict-aliasing, and horror stories)

You probably mean -fno-strict-aliasing since strict aliasing is enabled by default in gcc?

N == A + 1 would also be an aliasing issue (with *N > 1)
